# Can I disable the "Document was sent to printer" messages?

Tags: windows, printing

I have a few users complaining about the `document was sent to printer` messages that show up from the system tray.  Can they be turned off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Printers and Faxes
2. File Menu
3. Server Properties
4. Advanced tab
5. Informational messages for network printers (checkbox)